# Excel Len function

Tags: excel

I have a probleem in excel and i didnt figure it out how to do it right. anyway i'll give you an example to explain it correctly.

```
Name      Surname   Code
Martin    Kara      Maar4  (=> First two letters from Martin and 2nd en 3rd letters from surname and code is 4 and that's the lenght of the surname.
```

the probleem is i wanted to see the Maar4 as Maar04 not as Maar4.

I have already checked the formatcell but still didnt find it.

this is the code i wrote it:

=UPPER(LEFT(A2;2)& MID(B2;2;2)&LEN(B2))

thank you

edit: problem is solved. you guys are amazing. thank you

Comment: Hmmm have you looked into brute forcing the crap out of this by using `IF` depending on whether `LEN(B2)` is greater or smaller than 10?

Comment: ah yeah i forgat to say it. if its smaller then 10 then its has to be 04. So i need to use the if function but how exactly?

Comment: If the problem is solved accept the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using TEXT function to force 2 digits

=UPPER(LEFT(A2;2)& MID(B2;2;2))&TEXT(LEN(B2);"00")

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you're using `UPPER()` if you expect `Maar04`. If you do want to get `Marr04`, you would use:

```
=LEFT(A2;2)&MID(B2;2;2)&TEXT(LEN(B2);"00")
```

If you want to get `MAAR04`, then you'd use the uppercase:

```
=UPPER(LEFT(A2;2)&MID(B2;2;2)&TEXT(LEN(B2);"00"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're quite sure the length will never go above 99 you can try this hack:

```
=UPPER(LEFT(A2;2)& MID(B2;2;2)&RIGHT(LEN(B2)+100,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to use REPT() to achieve this.

See: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/rept-HP005209236.aspx

Your formula MIGHT look somehing like this;

```
=UPPER(LEFT(A2;2)& MID(B2;2;2)&REPT(0,LEN(B2)))
```